# Flatlist not showing data

Tags: react-native

i'm building application  with ReactNative and Expo , i want showing data using Flatlist i do importing data from external file.
there is no error upper but that data not showing on the screen and the screen empty .

```
import { GestureHandlerRefContext } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import Rect,{ useState }  from 'react';
import {View, Text,FlatList, StyleSheet,SafeAreaView} from 'react-native';
import Data from '../utils/Data'
import {PanGestureHandler, PanGestureHandlerGestureEvent} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import Animated, { useAnimatedGestureHandler, useAnimatedStyle, useSharedValue, withTiming } from 'react-native-reanimated';

const RequestsBody =() => {

 
  return (      
         <SafeAreaView>
        <FlatList
        data={Data}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        renderItem={({item}) => 
        <View>
        <Text>{item.name}</Text>
        <Text>{item.zone}</Text>
        <Text>{item.activities}</Text>
        </View>
        }
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
  )}



export default RequestsBody;
```

note: i want structure the Flatlist on right way so i can use Reanimated and handler and GestureHandler .
i want make animation effect swipe to delete  on the flatlist items

Comment: Please check by removing SafeAreaView.

Comment: even after remove SafeAreaView nothing shown

Comment: Your code is working for me. Maybe the typo in 
import Rect,{ useState }  from 'react';
change "Rect" into "React" and try

Comment: I changed it, thanks, but it still data doesn't show up

Comment: Okay then can you please share the structure of your data in "../utils/Data" and if possible the console error message if any

Comment: I have check structure of your data Data.js and the error was there thanks it work right now

Answer (score 0):

**For example**

```js
function App(){
  const data = ["item", "item2", "item3"];
  return (
    <FlatList data={data} renderItem={({item}) => (
      <Text>{item} </Text>
    )} />
  )

}
export default
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Note**FlatList handles data like this**
if the data is an array of object this what happens,
for example:
const data = [{name: "basit"}, {name: "Joseph"}, {name: "Adegoke"}];

Flatlist will get the data passed through the prop and store it inside an item property that is why we always destruct the item attribute.

<FlatList data={data} renderItem={({item}) => {item.name}}/>